# Appium: how to disable native location permission on iOS 17, it's now working by any method

Tags: ios, automation, appium, ui-automation

I'm trying to disable location permission on iOS while running appium no solution worked
I tried

```
capabilities.setCapability("locationServicesEnabled", false);
 capabilities.setCapability("locationServicesAuthorized", false);
 capabilities.setCapability("autoAcceptAlerts", false);
 capabilities.setCapability("autoGrantPermissions", true);
 capabilities.setCapability("gpsEnabled", false);
 capabilities.setCapability("noReset", false);
 capabilities.setCapability("fullReset", "false");
```

And also by detect element and click 'Don't allow' by this command

```
`driver.setSetting("acceptAlertButtonSelector", "**/XCUIElementTypeButton[label == 'Don't Allow']");`
```

interacting with 'Don't allow' button didn't work meanwhile it clicked on 'Precise:on/off'
[location native component](https://i.stack.imgur.com/foTDg.png)